# Can we just use ASP.NET MVC routing for MVC/AngularJS applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm quite new to AngularJS but have lots of experience with ASP.NET MVC.  For my next project, I'm thinking of using AngularJS (mainly for two-way data binding purposes). In the past I've used the KnockoutJS to achieve this.

Could someone please help me understand whether or not the design approach below is good?

1. MVC action will return JsonResult.
2. AngularJS will call these actions using $http service.
3. AngularJS will be used for binding JSON properties to HTML elements.
4. AngularJS will then call actions to post data.
5. MVC routing engine will be used instead of AngularJS'.

Comment: 1. better user a Web API, 2. better user $resouce, 5. why? if you make a spa use a client routing, why a server side routing, you are missing the point of a spa. As an extra better wait for angular 2.0 it will change a lot

Comment: UPDATE: It's not a SPA application but ASP.NET MVC application with Angular JS.

Comment: _"Angular JS is the future and should use it."_ .. You should use a tool when it meets your needs, not because it's trending.

Comment: @CarrieKendall you beat me to it

Comment: It will be used for data binding still haven't got my answer

Comment: Use Angular only in places you need two way data binding. Calling MVC actions that are returning binded partial view is more then enough in most applications, or using HTML imports with HandlebarsJS templates for some parts. Also there's no need to use Angular routing, just use MVC attribute routing an by leveraging bundles you can have routes.js, so in your client side you can have MyApp.routes.somerouteUrl and no magic strings when composing ajax calls.

Comment: I think it really depends on whether SEO is important for your app. If it isn't, have a catch-all route in MVC which routes everything through to angular, if it is let me know and I will reply with a more detailed answer. Also, *Angular JS is the future and should use it*, Angular 2 is coming out soon which is radically different and will basically require a front end rewrite to upgrade from 1.x which will be unsupported shortly after 2's release.